# Is this a bug or a feature in .NET Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5

I'm learning C# regex and am trying this:

```
String pattern = @"\(([0-9]+ *, *)*[0-9]+\)";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
if (!reg.IsMatch(TestGroupIDs))
    throw new Exception("Invalid TestGroupIDs string in App.config. The proper format is: (4,6)");
```

It is supposed validate any string like these: `"(3)"`, `"(3,4,5)"`, `"(3  ,4)"`, `"(3  ,      4)"`, etc.

and I tested it against this string: `"(4,6) OR 1=1"` and the regex matches. After trying a few other similar cases I found out that .NET Regex is treating the `" OR 1=1"` part as a Boolean expression. Is this a bug in .NET? Any work-around?

---

Given that people don't believe in me, I'm going to show some cases that I tried:

`"(4,6) || 1 = 1"` => `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DesktopMonitor.exe Incorrect syntax near '|'.`

`"(4,6) OR 1"` => `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '1'.`

I believe these result should validate my point.

---

Thanks for @false and @Rawling for correcting me. See @false's answer below. 
Take-away:

1. Use debugger before jumping into conclusion;
2. Trust Microsoft, even if they make crappy cell phones and browsers. (jk, WP and IE are actually pretty good now)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like (given the example failing strings) that you're trying to use a regex to protect yourself from SQL injection. That's the *wrong* tool for the job. Use parameters.

Comment: Yes I know that. I just want to know why this is happening.

Comment: Also, FYI, unlike JavaScript, the C# programming language has no support for regular expressions. You are asking about .NET regular expressions, not C# regular expressions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks a lot. I'm new to Windows programming and still trying to figure out what are the differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I found out that C# Regex is treating the " OR 1=1" part as a Boolean expression

No, it’s ignoring it completely. You’re checking whether your regular expression matches the string:

```
(4,6) OR 1=1
```

Well, it does! Right here:

```
(4,6) OR 1=1
-----
```

If you want to *validate* a string, you’ll usually want to anchor the regular expression to the beginning and end of the string – with `^` and `$`, respectively – so it can only match an entire string.

```
String pattern = @"^\(([0-9]+ *, *)*[0-9]+\)$";
```

Comment: This is not true for Regex.IsMatch()   I tried `"(4,6) || 1 = 1"` and this is what I got: `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DesktopMonitor.exe
Incorrect syntax near '|'.
`

Comment: Thanks though, for the quick response

Comment: @TengyuLiu [Yes, it is.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx) *Indicates whether the regular expression* finds a match  *in the input string.*

Comment: @TengyuLiu: That error occurs in some query you’re making; it has nothing to do with the regular expression. `||` is the string concatenation operator in standard SQL. I’d recommend you not throw user input into your query like that; there must be some way you can pass a list as a parameter.

Comment: @false I'm dealing with plain regex now, no SQL is involved.

Comment: @TengyuLiu: That’s, um… plainly not true. Are you using a debugger? Check which line gives you the error.

Comment: @Rawling Thanks for the link. But that doesn't answer why it's treating "OR 1=1" as bool expression...

Comment: @TengyuLiu It's not. Try `Regex.IsMatch("ab", "a")` and you will get true. That doesn't mean it's treating `b` as a boolean expression.

Comment: @Rawling I think you are right. I fell into a trap I made for myself. Feeling super dumb now.

Comment: @TengyuLiu No worries, happens to us all :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the end and beginning characters. Should be:

```
"^\(([0-9]+ *, *)*[0-9]+\)$"
```

Check here for regex help: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html